# Get a value from a data frame and add it to a new data frame

Tags: r

In the code below I want to add the value `3431933` from the first row, sixth column in `my_data` to the `new_data` object.

Instead it seems to be adding the number `2`.  Could you guys help me locate where I'm going wrong, or what my fundamental misunderstanding might be?

My Code:

```
print(my_data);
new_data <- {};
my_row <- my_data[1,];
print(my_row[1,6]);
new_data <- rbind(new_data, c(my_row[1,6]));
print(new_data);
```

Here's what I'm seeing in the printed output:

What's in `my_data`:

```
     V1            V2 V3   V4   V5       V6       V7            V8
1 10705 indiv7_ACTGAC  2  270  271  3431933  3442637          <NA>
2 41094 indiv7_ACTGAC  2  886  891 10296043 10337136 10297027.1114
3 18841 indiv7_ACTGAC  2 3497 3498 41414296 41433136          <NA>
                V9
1             <NA>
2 10335630.1686849
3             <NA>
```

What prints out for `my_row[1,6]`:

```
[1] 3431933
Levels: 10296043 3431933 41414296
```

What prints out for `new_data`:

```
         [,1]

[1,]    2
```

Comment: on a side note, in `R` there is no need for semi-colons (unless you are putting more than one line of code on a single line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a `factor` (ie, a categorical variable), which you need to convert to a number or character

```
#instead of: 
my_row[1,6]

# use: 
as.numeric(as.character(my_row[1,6]))
```

---

What gives away the fact that you are dealing with factors is that when you print it out, it is followed by `Levels: ....`   (You can also check by calling  `is.factor()`).

The number `2` that you are getting represents the second level of your variable.